# Any way to set name for VPCEndpointService via CloudFormation?

Tags: aws-cloudformation

I have a template containing:

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: "2010-09-09"
Resources:
  FooBarEndpointService:
    Type: AWS::EC2::VPCEndpointService
    Properties:
      NetworkLoadBalancerArns:
        - !Ref FooBarLoadBalancer
      AcceptanceRequired: true
```

When I apply this template, the created Endpoint Service (as viewed in AWS Console > VPC > Endpoint services) has `Name`: `–`. Is there a way to set that name via the CloudFormation template? Nothing in the table meaningfully identifies the endpoint service (all UIDs) so if I want to see information on a particular endpoint service, I have to click into every one in the table.